# Form posting JSON data which includes a url is being split at the query string of the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I need to post JSON data to an MVC controller that contains URL's. The JSON data looks like it's being split at the query string (=)

The JSON data looks like this:

```
"{"Files":[{"Title":"test","OriginalFileName":"",
"FileName":"http://company.domain.com/auth.aspx?enrollmentkey=APK54cd1546a8454d4ca79ded89a78f8698",
"Categories":[{"CategoryId":76,"SubCategoryId":182,"CatId":"CatId0"}],
"TypeId":"84",
"Tags":["Select Tag(s)..."],
"TagIds":[],
"Roles":[],
"MemberOnly":false,
"ContentTypeId":7,
"Id":0,
"IsPublished":true,
"PublishDate":""}]}"
```

Debugging, I see that it's being split into

KEY (Request.Form.GetKey(0)):

```
{"Files":[{"Title":"Test","OriginalFileName":"","FileName":"http://company.domain.com/auth.aspx?enrollmentkey
```

VALUE (Request.Form.GetValue(0)):

```
APK54cd1546a8454d4ca79ded89a78f8698","Categories":[{"CategoryId":110,"SubCategoryId":111,"CatId":"CatId0"}],"TypeId":"69","Tags":["Select Tag(s)..."],"TagIds":[],"Roles":[],"MemberOnly":false,"ContentTypeId":7,"Id":0,"IsPublished":true,"PublishDate":""}]}
```

Does the JSON data needs to be escaped at the = or the whole thing needs to be encoded or am I missing something?

I should note that I'm using knockout's ko.toJSON(js) to create the JSON although I'm not sure that is relevant.

I also noticed that chrome dev tools also seems to recognize the Key-Val split:

[image]

Comment: Can you encode your URL before submitting the JSON?

Comment: What is the value of the Content-Type header when you post?

Comment: @BrianRogers the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: It needs to be application/json if you are posting json data.

Comment: Could you show the code where you are sending the request? How are you constructing the JSON data and are you sending it as an AJAX request?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I was using knockout's ko.toJSON function and sending the data via jQuery.ajax() but properly setting the Content-Type fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending JSON data to the server, the Content-Type header needs to be set to `application/json`.  If it is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then the server will try to interpret the JSON as key-value pairs as in a URL.  This is why your JSON string is getting broken in two at the `=`.